# Getting a currency format pattern from AngularJS filter

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, currency

I'm interested in creating a filter that would accept an amount, ISO 4217 currency code, and fraction size, and return the amount in that format. I noticed that AngularJS has `goog.i18n.currency.getGlobalCurrencyPattern` in `i18n/closure/currencySymbols.js`, but I'm relatively new to Angular and not sure if it is possible to use it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The currency pattern and symbols are just that.  It determines how to display a number.  It will not convert it from XXX to XXX.  You will have to do the converting part based on the current conversion rates.

As far as using the built-in currency formatting, there are multiple ways: in the template, in the code.

In the template:

```
<div>{{myCurrencyValue | currency:'XXX'}}</div>
```

In the code:

```
var formatted = $filter('currency')(myCurrencyValue, 'XXX')
```

In both cases, `'XXX'` is optional [and is symbol] and will use the default currency for current locale

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/N7YuP/

More information can be found here: [Currency Docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3acurrency)

**UPDATE**

Example with ISO 4217 codes using custom filter: http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/N7YuP/3/

Note: ISO 4217 doesn't dictate the currency symbols, I used [this](http://www.xe.com/symbols.php) for symbol reference and mapped them.

Comment: My understanding is that the existing option on the currency filter is for a different currency symbol.  I would really like to take a number, ISO 4217 Currency Code, and fraction size and have it formatted.  For example: var formattedValue = $filter('myfilter')(1000, 'EUR', 2);

Comment: Your better off creating a filter and utilizing JS that has already been made like money.js which will also do conversion for you.  If you would like I will change my answer to create a new filter using this.

Comment: I went ahead and updated it using a custom filter to use the ISO codes.  I had to custom map the ISO codes to the symbols.  You can see that mapping the in fiddle.  I am also using accounting.js for formatting.

Comment: Thanks for helping and your quick solution!  The thing is that I don't really want to maintain the formatting rules.  I'm concerned about variations in thousands separators, decimal separators, negative numbers, etc.  That is why I am interested in the goog.i18n.currency library.

Comment: I understand.  Google's i18n for currencies just isn't that powerful.  Its explained in the Gotcha's section: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n.  Also, I don't think the formatting changes very much, you can just set it once and forget.  Just need to use a little elbow grease to set it up.

Comment: @TheSharpieOne Have you checked your example using INR as currency code? It simply fails, even the digits are not shown for INR.

Comment: @SajidAli It appears that when I generated the formatting map (from http://www.xe.com/symbols.php) INR didn't come through, if you look it is `"INR": {"text":"","uniDec":"","uniHex":""}`. I looked at http://www.xe.com/symbols.php and the information for INR is blank there.  If you know the missing information (symbol, uniDec, uniHex) it can be added and it would work.

Comment: @TheSharpieOne True, the data was missing.
what I was pointing out is if the current data is missing, then currency symbol should not appear, and the numeric value should appear.
It should show the output as `formatted: 100.12`. Same is case for when currency code is non existent like `testCurrencyCode`, output should not completely disappear. Can this be done?