# Format currency in AngularJS in ngModel

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to format currency when the page loads using AngularJS. But it doesn't work if I use the filter currency in ngModel.It seems to work only for {{var |currency}}.

P.S.:I want it to work on ngModel and I want the currency to be formatted when the page loads.

Comment: Can you show the actual code that doesn't work?

Comment: Can you show that code have you tried. In js filter can be done using syntax `$filter('currency')(amount[, symbol])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have the filter within the html and not in ng-model, this is an alternative:

`<input type="text" ng-model="var" value="var|currency"/>`

You can add it to value attribute.

Comment: This is not working if the input type is number. any way to do that ?

Comment: If the input is a number, you will not be able to have the currency symbol on it.

Comment: Getting this error :
The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?
Details : input type="number"
changes to type="text"
Now getting no error but still not working.

Comment: This is not working for me. Is there any condition for **value="var|currency"** ?

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="App">
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <span>Amount1: {{amount1 | currency:"USD$"}}</span><br/>
    <span>Symbol2: <input ng-model="symbol2"/></span><br/>
    <span>Amount2: <input ng-model="amount2"/></span><br/>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
angular.module('App', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.amount1 = 1234.56;
  $scope.symbol2 = 'USD$';
  $scope.amount2 = '1234.56';
}
```

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/daSnET?p=preview)

If that does not help, check this:
[Getting a currency format pattern from AngularJS filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745452/getting-a-currency-format-pattern-from-angularjs-filter)

Comment: Its not right way to format ngModel I am not seeing any ngModel in html which is using currency formator